# how to display a value(in text field) from one form(after submitting it) to another form (both are on the same page)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So, I have the form1 where i am giving values in two fields and ***submitting it***,

```
    <form action="new_cand.php" name="form1" method="post">

         <input type="number" name="aadhar_r" id="aadhar_r"  required/>

          <input type="text" name="cand_r" id="cand_r" required/>

       <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  onclick="setValues();" />

     </form>
```

I want these values to automatically be written and visible in the two **textinput** and **numberinput** fields in form2.

```
<form action="in_cand.php" name="form2" method="post"> 

   <input type="number" id="a_number" name="a_number" required>

   <input type="text" id="cid" name="cid" required>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />

 </form>
```

how do i use javascript to automatically set values visible and ready to submit 
 to the fields in form2 ???

**Note**: i'm using two forms because they both have different actions after clicking submit and both the forms are on the same page.

Comment: have you considered just updating the action after the first subit, instead of making a duplicate form?

Also unless you submit your form asynchronously, your page will reload before you can submit the second form.

maybe consider posting both jquery, then you can set in code where both should post to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one small example using `id` hashes, with this idea, I think you can start, object `hash` will have pair list,

You can restrict specific form by mentioning id of it, in place of `$('form :input').on()`:

```js
var hash = {
  aadhar_r : 'a_number',
  cand_r : 'cid'
}

$('form :input').on('keyup',function(){
    if(this.id in hash){
          $('#'+hash[this.id]).val($(this).val())
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="new_cand.php" name="form1" method="post">
  <input type="number" name="aadhar_r" id="aadhar_r" required/>
  <input type="text" name="cand_r" id="cand_r" required/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="setValues();" />
</form>

<form action="in_cand.php" name="form2" method="post">
  <input type="number" id="a_number" name="a_number" required>
  <input type="text" id="cid" name="cid" required>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can serialize your first form and send it directly to the server. Then you get the value from the input field and set it to the other input field.

**Form 1:**

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="number" name="aadhar_r" id="aadhar_r"  required/>
    <input type="text" name="cand_r" id="idOfInput1" required/>
    <button id="submit" />
</form>
```

**Script:**

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
     $.post("new_cand.php", $("#form1").serializeArray(), function () { /* Nothing to do with new_cand.php data */});
     $("#idOfInput2").val($("#idOfInput1").val());
});
```

**Form 2:**

```
<form action="in_cand.php" name="form2" method="post"> 
   <input type="number" id="a_number" name="a_number" required>
   <input type="text" id="idOfInput2" name="cid" required>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
 </form>
```

**Attention**: this is not tested, requires jQuery and is for a post method